# Scikit-Learn Linear Regression using Datetime Values and forecasting

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, scikit-learn, forecasting

Below is a sample of the dataset.

| row_id | datetime | energy |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2008-03-01 00:00:00 | 1259.985563 |
| 2 | 2008-03-01 01:00:00 | 1095.541500 |
| 3 | 2008-03-01 02:00:00 | 1056.247500 |
| 4 | 2008-03-01 03:00:00 | 1034.742000 |
| 5 | 2008-03-01 04:00:00 | 1026.334500 |

The dataset has datetime values and energy consumption for that hour in `object` and `float64` dtypes.  I want to predict the energy using the `datetime` column as the single feature.

I used the following code

```
    train['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(train['datetime'])
    X = train.iloc[:,0]
    y = train.iloc[:,-1]
```

I could not pass the single feature as Series to the fit object as I got the following error.

```
ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
array=['2008-03-01T00:00:00.000000000' '2008-03-01T01:00:00.000000000'
 '2008-03-01T02:00:00.000000000' ... '2018-12-31T21:00:00.000000000'
 '2018-12-31T22:00:00.000000000' '2018-12-31T23:00:00.000000000'].
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or  
array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
```

So I converted their shapes as suggested.

```
 X = np.array(X).reshape(-1,1)
 y = np.array(y).reshape(-1,1)
 
 from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
 model_1 = LinearRegression()
 model_1.fit(X,y)
 
 test = pd.to_datetime(test['datetime'])
 test = np.array(test).reshape(-1,1)
 
 predictions = model_1.predict(test)
```

The LinearRegression object fitted the feature `X` and target `y` without raising any error. But when I passed the test data to the predict method, it threw the following error.

```
TypeError: The DType <class 'numpy.dtype[datetime64]'> could not be promoted by <class 'numpy.dtype[float64]'>. 
This means that no common DType exists for the given inputs. 
For example they cannot be stored in a single array unless the dtype is `object`. 
The full list of DTypes is: (<class 'numpy.dtype[datetime64]'>, <class 'numpy.dtype[float64]'>)
```

I can't wrap my head around this error.  How can I use the datetime values as a single feature and apply simple linear regression to predict the target value and do TimeSeries forecasting? Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can not train on a datetime format. If you want the model to learn datetime features then consider splitting it into day, month, weekday, weekofyear, hour etc to learn patterns with seasonality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not train on a datetime format. If you want the model to learn datetime features then consider splitting it into day, month, weekday, weekofyear, hour etc to learn patterns with seasonality:

```py
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error, r2_score

df = pd.DataFrame(data=[["2008-03-01 00:00:00",1259.985563],["2008-03-01 01:00:00",1095.541500],["2008-03-01 02:00:00",1056.247500],["2008-03-01 03:00:00",1034.742000],["2008-03-01 04:00:00",1026.334500]], columns=["datetime","energy"])
df["datetime"] = pd.to_datetime(df["datetime"])
features = ["year", "month", "day", "hour", "weekday", "weekofyear", "quarter"]
df[features] = df.apply(lambda row: pd.Series({"year":row.datetime.year, "month":row.datetime.month, "day":row.datetime.day, "hour":row.datetime.hour, "weekday":row.datetime.weekday(), "weekofyear":row.datetime.weekofyear, "quarter":row.datetime.quarter }), axis=1)

X = df[features]
y = df[["energy"]]

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2)

model = LinearRegression()
model.fit(X_train, y_train)

y_pred = model.predict(X_test)

print(mean_squared_error(y_test, y_pred))
```